# stay anonymous in wireless network even if you are part of it

Tags: wifi, anonymity, mac-address

Even though router knows you are always there, what are some other things we can do rather than changing MAC address

Ok the thing is there is wireless access point(router) and a user(owner of router) and another person who knows password and SSID of AP.

Is their any way to remain uncaught.

- Can we clear router logs
- what if use same MAC as client

Will [Who Is Using My WIFI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiumwifi/)-like tools uncover the attacker to client

Answer (score 1):

Remaining anonymous on a wireless network doesn't mean the operators won't detect your existence in the network. It's essential to understand the core concept of what is going on here: you're asking the access point (AP) to give you data, the AP will give you said data, it **will** be possible to detect that *someone* is using the connection.

To remain anonymous you should either constantly change your MAC address; IP address; and clear your cookies (Captive Portal software can identify you using a cookie in your browser), or you can impersonate a legitimate client by using their MAC address; IP address (in case it was assigned statically); and the identifying cookie in the browser.

Please note that it's not common for the regular access points to have Captive Portal software, especially in a home or small office environment. So it's relatively safe to ignore the cookie part.

Comment: I'm not sure how changing your IP address would help stay anonymous from a router in _any_ scenario. Not to mention, the IP address is usually assigned by the router, not by your computer. And _constantly_ changing your MAC address (rather than using a single spoofed value) just makes you stand out.